# Using a MySQL query and BASH, how can I Delete, Rename, or Move all image files used by Drupal nodes before a certain date?

Tags: mysql, bash, drupal

***BACKSTORY IF YOU'RE INTERESTED:*** A friend of mine owns a magazine and has been publishing a corresponding Drupal 7 website since 2011. The site has thousands of articles and around 50,000 images supporting those articles. Unfortunately, due to copyright trolling attorneys, he's already been hit with a couple of copyright infringement lawsuits over images that he thought were from "creative commons." Since his first lawsuit in 2016, he's made sure all images are from a stock image company. But apparently, very recently, yet another image from before 2016 has caused another copyright troll to seek $18,000 (it's literally a photo of a hotdog by the way). Nevertheless, his business insurance company just wants to pay the settlement fees rather than risk anything in court, but has demanded that all potentially suspect images be deleted from the site going forward. Since 95% of the stories that have been published on his site have had fewer than 1000 views anyway (they are worth less than 50 cents from advertisers), he has agreed to take all those images down because $.50 is definitely not worth the risk of feeding any more trolls.

**QUESTION:** What's the best way to delete, rename or move all the images that are connected to a story node before a certain date in 2016? It would be nice if we could temporarily just change the filenames on the filesystem from "`trollfood.jpg`" to "`trollfood.jpg.bak`" (or something) so that if/when he can ensure that an image is in fact in the public domain, he can revive it. It would also be nice, if we could replace all the potentially suspect images links (in the db) with a placeholder image links for the time being (so that people can still read the article without wondering where the images have gone...perhaps the image will be a brief explanation of the trolling situation). Anyway, it's been a minute since I've done anything with Drupal, so I've forgotten how drupal links files to nodes (and he has some custom content types powering his main articles).

I've been able to get all the potentially suspect images in a list via mysql:

```sql
SELECT fid, filename, timestamp, from_unixtime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%e") 
FROM drupal7_therooster.file_managed 
where timestamp between unix_timestamp('2011-01-01') and unix_timestamp('2017-01-01');

// here's sample output:
# fid   filename                        timestamp   from_unixtime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%e")
6154    _MG_5147.jpg                    1373763148  2013-07-14
6155    _MG_5179.jpg                    1373763148  2013-07-14
6161    The Lone Bellow (4 of 5).jpg    1373866156  2013-07-15
6162    The Lone Bellow (1 of 5).jpg    1373866156  2013-07-15
```

Now, how can I use this to find the potentially offending stories that uses these images, and perform the following:

1. Create a list of all the stories that use these images so I can save this in case he ever wants to revive these images. I know SQL well enough...I just don't know which tables keep which data.
2. Create a query that replaces these image associations in these stories to a placeholder image (so if story uses "trollfood.jpg", that story now uses "safetyimageplaceholder.jpg" instead. Some stories have multiple images attached to them.
3. Once all the potentially offending articles reference a placeholder image instead, I still need to move all the offending files so they can't be accessed by lawyers...I have access via ssh by the way. Are there any good ways of using bash commands to ONLY move/rename files that match the list I generate from an SQL query? I just want to be careful not to delete/rename/move any images that were NOT part of the query. Bear in mind the file creation date in the filesystem is all 2017+ on the server because the server was moved (or copied) in 2017 so the file system's original creation dates are inaccurate.

I know this is a long question...and it involves a Drupal site, but I think I might need the help of proper SQL and bash experts, so I've posted it here instead of the Drupal specific stackexchange. I'm totally open to any suggestions if another completely different approach is better suited for this problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question. I had to do three main things:

**STEP ONE:** Create a query for Drupal's MySQL database that would give me a list of all potential copyright infringing files that were being used by nodes created between 2012 and 2017:

```
SELECT fm.fid, fm.filename, 
n.title, n.nid, from_unixtime(n.created, "%Y-%m-%d") as 'node_date'
FROM file_managed fm 
JOIN file_usage fu ON fm.fid = fu.fid 
JOIN node n ON fu.id = n.nid
WHERE created BETWEEN unix_timestamp('2012-01-01') AND unix_timestamp('2017-01-01')
ORDER BY node_date
```

This is a moderately complex query, but basically it joins columns from three tables (Drupal 7's `file_managed`, `node`, and `file_usage` tables). The `file_usage` table is a shared key register of which files (via `fid`) are used on which nodes (via `nid`).

**STEP TWO:** Organize and filter the data to create a list of files.

I filtered and ordered the results by node created dates. I got about 48K records from the join query in step one, and then I created a google spreadsheet to clean up and sort the data. Here's a [sample of the google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PfqR_ORWecVvWmKhmnG-tE030LjnIQNR6i9dgQJ2VdU/edit#gid=1918029454). This sheet also includes data from the node_counter table which tracks page views for each node. Using a simple `VLOOKUP` function to match the total page views for each `nid` on the main sheet, now the main sheet can be sorted by page views. I did this so I could prioritize which images attached to each nodes/article I should check first. This is the sql query I used to get that data from the db by the way:

```
SELECT nid, totalcount, daycount, from_unixtime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d") as 'date'
FROM node_counter
ORDER BY totalcount DESC
```

**STEP THREE:** Write a Shell Script that will take our filtered list of files, and move them somewhere safe (and off the public webserver).

Basically, I needed a simple BASH script that would use the list of files from step two to move them off the web server. Bear in mind, when each image file is uploaded to the server, Drupal can (and did) created about a dozen different aspect ratios and sizes, and placed each one of these copies into corresponding folders. For example, one image filename could be copied and resized into:

- files/coolimage.jpg
- files/large/coolimage.jpg
- files/hero/coolimage.jpg
- files/thumbnails/coolimage.jpg
- files/*/coolimage.jpg etc etc.

So, I have to take a list of ~50K filenames, and check for those filenames in a dozen different subfolders, and if they are present in a subfolder, move each of them to an archived folder all while preserving the folder/file tree structure and leaving behind files that are "safe" to keep on the public web server. So...I ended up writing [THIS simple script and open sourced it on Github in case anyone else might benefit from it](https://github.com/Doomd/bulk_file_mover).

*That's it! Thankfully I knew some SQL and how to use google spreadsheets...and some basic bash..and well, how to use google and solve problems. If google users are able to find this helpful in the future...cheers!*